# Self signed certificate in certificate chain error after bootstrap ember server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am inside coorpration proxy and I have an certification error everytime I start the ember server,

```
➜  Dummy ember s
Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.

Just getting started with Ember? Please visit http://localhost:4200/ember-getting-started to get going

Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
{ Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1060:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:584:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38) code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' }

Build successful - 16244ms.
```

I have try to use `ember s --ssl=false` but the issue persist.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe set `disableAnalytics` to `true`  in your `.ember-cli` file?

Comment: Thanks the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Lux,

All you need to do is to change the content of `.ember-cli` to snippet below,

```
{
  "disableAnalytics": true
}
```